# how to reload a div, created by a while loop using jquery?

Tags: php, jquery

here is my problem : 
if I try to load a div outside the while loop `(.testt)` it works fine

```
$("#comment_area_"+n_comm_text).load("pages/userprofil.php .testt");
```

but if I use the same code to load a div inside the while loop it just make the `#comment_area` disappears :

```
$("#comment_area_"+n_comm_text).load("pages/userprofil.php comment_area_"+n_comm_text);
```

the while loop :

```
<?php 
$i=0;
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($quser)){
$i++;?>
<div class="comment_area" id="comment_area_<?php echo($i);?>">
//some code
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

I hope my problem is clear , any help is very welcome . Thank you

Comment: You need to either end your PHP block before you write the HTML, or you need to `echo` the HTML within the PHP block.  What you have above is mixing them together and will not work.

Comment: Missing `#` for `#comment_area...` : `.load("pages/userprofil.php #comment_area_"+n_comm_text);`

Comment: Check your *rendered* html without the php hieroglpyhs

Comment: no , just because I tried to write a minature of my code here , I forgot to mention the Php blocks , may you please reCheck my post , I've just edited it

Comment: @freedomn-m thank you that was a good remark , but still doesn't work

Comment: Please guys , I've been thinking and I figured out that maybe if jquery give me just a blank white nothing is because the loop is inside pages/userprofil.php . Can that be the problem ? please I need help , I'm stuck

Comment: **Tip:** Get it to work with hand-written html/javascript (ie without the php stuff).  Then add the php stuff for the db fetch/loop and see what the difference in the *rendered* output is.

Answer (score 0):

in your while loop, make sure to separate HTML from PHP. Pay special attention to quotes and double quotes, and how to concatenate strings with variables. Hope it helps.

```
$i=0;
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($quser)){
$i++;
echo '<div class="comment_area" id="comment_area_'.$i.'">';
//some code
echo '</div>';
}
```

Comment: I edited my code , may you please check again my post

Comment: Echo variables without parentheses, see that you have <?php echo($i);?> instead of <?php echo $i; ?>. If the divs aren't showing at all on your HTML, the issue comes from the loop. But you also need to check freedomn-m's answer regarding the hash.

Comment: yeah still the same problem . Thank you anyway ;)